# Not able to set tshark preferences from command line

Tags: command-line-interface, wireshark, tshark

I am using tshark on a CentOS server, where wireshark is NOT installed, only tshark, editcap and capinfos are installed. I do NOT have the file `$HOME/.wireshark/preferences`.

However, I get the proper output for the command `tshark -G defaultprefs`

So I am trying to override the ignore_wep preference using `tshark -r input.pcap -o wlan.ignore_wep: Yes - with IV` but getting the output `tshark: Invalid -o flag "wlan.ignore_wep:"`

Any clue on what exactly is going wrong or where I can find the tshark preferences file ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there are spaces in the option value you are trying to set, you need to wrap it in quotes:

```
tshark -r input.pcap -o "wlan.ignore_wep: Yes - with IV"
```

The default preferences are compiled into the wireshark shared library.

Comment: I had tried wrapping in quotes, but only for the "Yes - with IV" part. It didn't occur to me that the entire option is handled as a string !